# How to restrict access to fonts while using the new font-management feature in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, ios13

I want to create a fonts App where users can purchase new fonts and use them systemwide in iOS 13.

But according to this [WWDC-2019 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/227) about the new font-management feature, you need to submit all the fonts with the App-bundle, either in an asset-catalog or as on-demand resources.

If you want to restrict users to access only the fonts they have purchased, it makes sense to add these fonts as on-demand resources. But even then the un-purchased fonts are not all that secure.

What would be the best way to ensure that only the purchased fonts are accessible to a user?

Comment: Why do you say _even then the un-purchased fonts are not all that secure_? What’s your threat model? Keep in mind fonts are generally easy to steal. A dedicated person could just get your font on the internet anyway.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBrager, I agree with what you are saying. But is there a way to restrict access to the on-demand resources in general?

Comment: The threat model is, someone could just download the assets using the tags for the on-demand resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the font files may not be encrypted and must go through App Store review. So I think your best bet is:

- Use secure random generation for the on-demand resource tag strings
- Don’t bundle the tags in the client
- Provide the tags to your client from your server only over a secure connection, and only after verifying the in-app purchase receipt with Apple
- If you think it’s worth it, periodically cycle the ODR tags

Imperfect, but hopefully good enough. I doubt there will be much font piracy on iOS due to the difficulty of jailbreaking & side loading icons.

Comment: If this is insufficient, I think you’ll have to file a radar requesting something better.